# NetLogo: assign matrix values to patches

Tags: matrix, netlogo

Let's say I wanted to assign the values of a 4 x 5 matrix to patches such that

```
patch 1 1 [x] = matrix 1,1
patch 1 2 [x] = matrix 1,2
..
patch 4,5 [x] = matrix 4,5
```

is there a way to do this in NetLogo?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you're representing the matrix, but in general doing something like

`ask patches [ set x matrix pxcor pycor ]`

should do the trick (assuming `x` is a patch variable and `matrix` is a reporter that gets a value from the matrix).

Comment: A similar approach can be used to color the patches in the world if the world is the same size as the matrix (the use case which led to me finding this question):
ask patches [
  let my-val (matrix:get some-matrix pxcor pycor)
  ifelse (my-val = 1) [set pcolor blue][set pcolor white]
]